# Facebook Graph ERM

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, entity-relationship

one short question: is there any Entity-Relationship-Model of all the data that Facebook stores / provides? It would be quite useful since it would give an overview of all the entities, their connections and maybe the required permissions... Maybe someone knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen anything like that in the official documentation.